# How do I delete the white background of a table? Foundation Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, css

My problem is that I added foundation rails to my project that is created in ruby ​​on rails and I wanted to create a small table, but this table when I create creates a white background, what I want to do is make my table transparent without Background of no color.

I tried to put a class and assigning properties but it does not work, also add the style directly, delete the cookies just in case but still does not change color, only resize.

[image]

file .css

```
.tabla {
    width:80%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

file .html.erb

```
<table border="2"  class="tabla">
  <tr>
    <td>Film Affinity</td>
    <td><%= image_tag "film_affinity.png",:class=>"imagenPie"%></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>IMDB</td>
    <td><%= image_tag "imdb.png",:class=>"imagenPie"%></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Sensa Cine</td>
    <td><%= image_tag "sensacine.png",:class=>"imagenPie"%></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Foundation sets the background color using the selectors: `table thead, table tbody, table tfoot` and `table tbody tr:nth-child(even)` for every other row.

https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/scss/components/_table.scss

---

The following CSS should set all rows to have a transparent background color:

```
table tbody tr:nth-child(even), table tbody {
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

Comment: yes, the code it works, but is necessary add !important

Answer (score 0):

It seems ok to me. Perhaps there is some other rules that are overriding your `.tabla` css. You may try to add an `!important` and see if that fixes it:

```
.tabla {
  width:80%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Otherwise, the color may come with the `td` or `tr` instead from the `table`. In that case, add the following rule:

```
.tabla tr, .tabla td {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Note that using `!important` is usually a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css). Try to search and clean your css code instead of using that clause.

Also, the `border` attribute of tables is [deprecated now](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_border.asp). You should use `border` [css property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp) instead.